# Extension permission for Chrome settings menu (chrome://settings)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension, it listens the chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener and disconnects the user when chrome window is closed.

I want to execute script (chrome.tabs.executeScript) in the "chrome://settings-frame" page.

In this page i am going to manually disconnect user from Chrome.

(by running this code: chrome.send('SyncSetupStopSyncing', [deleteProfile]);)

Is this permission possible?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no permission that would allow you to access `chrome://` URL scheme. This is an explicit safety mechanism against potentially malicious changes to Chrome settings.

You can get the access if you enable `extensions-on-chrome-urls` flag, but obviously you can't do that on machines you don't fully control.

Additionally, there is no API to manipulate users in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Xan. You have said that "... there is no API to manipulate users in Chrome." This means, it is impossible to "disconnect from chrome" automatically?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.