# Selenium - Python, cant find the element

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I just started my first project with selenium using python. 
My first task is to login to chrome using 'Sign to chrome' button, but I just can't click it: [Sign to chrome button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeGCm.png)

Button HTML:

```
<paper-button class="action-button" role="button" tabindex="0" animated="" aria-disabled="false" elevation="0">
                  Sign in to Chrome
                </paper-button>
```

This is the link: [chrome://settings/people](http://chrome://settings/people)

I've tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('action-button').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//paper-button[@class='action-button']').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('paper-button.action-button').click()
```

Nothing worked.

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"paper-button:not([raised]).action-button"}
```

Comment: adding screenshot is bad practice instead you can add html snip of that element also add error stacktrace

Comment: @Dev Yep, your'e right. first message here, here to learn. just edited it, let me know if its better now

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use AutoIt pip and you can try below code:

Install Autoit:

```
pip install -U pyautoit
```

Use below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import autoit
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("chrome://settings/")
autoit.send('{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}')
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: Thats awesome, ill give it a try. but just so ill know - how can catch that button using only selenium?

Comment: Thanks, let me know if it works I will try to fine pure selenium code soon.

Comment: @Benjamin Found some reference and it looks it's not possible this url might give you details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26473101/8148899