# Elements cannot be found on chrome://settings/content

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

## Issue:

Upon webdriving to `chrome://settings/content` using chromedriver and selenium, I came across the issue where no elements could be found even if I gave the exact xpath copied from chrome dev tools or if I varied my search method e.g. using `find_element_by_tag_name()` instead and looking for more basic elements e.g. the `<h1>Settings</h1>` element.

This is not an issue of my search method as I can go to any other web page and select elements correctly.

Is this a security feature of Chrome which stops webdriving in their settings or something alike?

## Specs:

- `Python3.7`
- `Chromedriver`
- `Selenium` - latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it Shadow-DOM, using CSS selector select the `/deep/`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('settings-ui /deep/ h1')
# or
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('* /deep/ h1')
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there is no permission that would allow you to access `chrome://` URL scheme.

This is an explicit safety mechanism against potentially malicious changes to Chrome settings.

You can get the access if you enable `extensions-on-chrome-urls` flag, but obviously you can't do that on machines you don't fully control.

Additionally, there is no API to manipulate users in Chrome.

source: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472273)